# Weekdays 9:00 till 17:00 every 30 minutes Spring Cron job

Tags: java, spring, cron

I tried this expression:

```
0 0/30 9-17 * * MON-FRI
```

Which works almost as I want it to except that it runs 1 extra time at 17:30, how can I make last execution in a day at 17:00?

Comment: `@Scheduled` is repeatable, so how about adding two schedules: one with `0 0/30 9-16 * * MON-FRI` and one for `0 0 17 * * MON-FRI`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use

```
0 0/30 9-16,17 * * MON-FRI
```

But I'm not sure if this works using Spring